# mySQL - minute data has missing minutes

Tags: mysql, import

I have a database with a cityname table and a moisture table. Details are as follows:

```
'cityname' has 2 columns:  
-city_ID <- integer and primary key that increments automatically  
-city_full_name <- character name i.e. boston, toronto, new york city etc...  

'citymoisture' has 7 columns:  
-city_ID <- tied to the city_ID field via a Foreign Key  
-date  
-time  
-open  
-high  
-low  
-close
```

I uploaded the data into the db using the following commands

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE     'Boston 1 Minute Moisture.txt'
    -> INTO TABLE           moisture
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    -> IGNORE 1 LINES
    -> (@date, @time, open, high, low, close)
    -> SET                  city_id=4,
    ->                       date=STR_TO_DATE(@date, '%m/%d/%Y'),
    ->                       time=STR_TO_DATE(@time, '%h:%i:%s %p');
```

The problem that I have discovered is that there are gaps in the data. The sensor sometimes fails to save when the minute cycle comes around and so there are periods when the time between 2 successive rows is greater than 1 minute. I want to identify those gaps and insert my own data i.e. ideally a carbon copy of the previous minute's data.

The sample output of the data file:

```
Date, Time, Open, High, Low, Close  
1/4/1999,9:31:00 AM,0.943,0.943,0.943,0.943  
1/4/1999,9:32:00 AM,0.943,0.943,0.943,0.943
1/4/1999,9:33:00 AM,0.943,0.943,0.943,0.943
1/4/1999,9:35:00 AM,0.943,0.943,0.943,0.943
1/4/1999,9:36:00 AM,0.943,0.943,0.943,0.943
```

See in this example the data for 9:34 is missing. What I want to do is find a way to indentify where this is happening and make changes. I think I might just copy the data in the previous minute into the missing minute row.

Something like If time[1] - time[0] > 1 then insert the previous row in between. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where do you want to make this modification? The database after it's imported or the text file before the import?

Comment: Each city moisture file is 60MBs and has about 1.8 million rows of data so that might play a role in determining where I make the modification. In the end I want a complete data set so all cities have the same number of data points. What do you suggest my friend?

Comment: Lots of data either way. My gut reaction was to say edit the text file keeping the import clean. Then you can use existing tools to rip through the text and replicate rows.

Comment: Yeah I wrote a perl script to do this but even then it is a messy situation as there are so many cases that result in missing gaps....   Slowly cleaning it all.

Answer (score 1):

Create a table with all of the minutes in it (1440 rows) and do a left outer join to your data table after you've loaded it.  Any rows that are null are missing data.

Don't forget the indexes.